# Throttle my page scroll so it only skips one slide

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll, revolution-slider

seems like such an easy fix but i just cant seem to get it. I need to throttle or debounce my scroll in JavaScript so that the slide only skips to the next slide. At the moment it is counting the number of times the scroll clicks and then scrolls that many slides. I am using revolution slider on a WordPress site.

I have the current code to make the slide use on mouse scroll skip to next slide.

```html
(function() {
 
 // change "revapi1" here to whatever API name your slider uses (see notes below)
 var slider = revapi1;
 
 slider.parent().on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  
  if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
  
   slider.revprev();
   
  }
  else {
  
   slider.revnext();
            
   
  }
  
 });
 
})()
```

But as you can see the problem on www.bladeworks.co.za/blade_website_new it skips the slides dependent on the mouse scrolls done.

Is there anyway that I can edit this code to make it just skip one slide and go only to the next one?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't see the problem, it slides normally. Have you fixed it in the meantime?

Comment: hey Goran, it scrolls and slides normally, but if you do a big drag on the scroll wheel it skips specific slides. I want even a big scroll only to skip one slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
        threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
        var last,
        deferTimer;
    return function () {
        var context = scope || this;

        var now = +new Date,
        args = arguments;
        if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
        // hold on to it
             clearTimeout(deferTimer);
             deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
             last = now;
             fn.apply(context, args);
        }, threshhold);
        } else {
             last = now;
             fn.apply(context, args);
        }
    };
 }
```

refrenced from here [simple throttle function](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls)

```
  element.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',throttle(function(){
      ...
  }))
```

Or you can use a "lock" to lock your event handler when slider is moving:

```
  element.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(){
      if(!element.hasClass('locked')){
          element.addClass('locked');
          ...//process, move next, move previous
          element.removeClass('locked');
      }
  })
```

this one is much easy to understand

a complete one:

```
 (function() {


       var slider = revapi1;

       slider.parent().on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',throttle(function(event) {
             if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ||     event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                slider.revprev();
             }else {
                slider.revnext();
             }
      },250));
    function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
         threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
         var last,
         deferTimer;
         return function () {
             var context = scope || this;

             var now = +new Date,
             args = arguments;
             if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
                  // hold on to it
                  clearTimeout(deferTimer);
                  deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                       last = now;
                       fn.apply(context, args);
                  }, threshhold);
              } else {
                  last = now;
                  fn.apply(context, args);
              }
        };
     }

 })()
```

Comment: Hey Jilykate, must i replace my existing code with the above?

Comment: this is just an option. there are lots of ways make your function "throttle". I re-edit my answer, you can also use a lock as above.

Comment: I feel like an idiot haha ! i cant get them to work with the code that i currently have. Would you be able to post it with the complete code at all?

Comment: @user3274603 as required~

Comment: thank you so much i see exactly what you did there :) and it worked. is there any quick way i can change it to not delay but just pause the function? because it sits on the slide now for 10 seconds. But wont let me scroll to other slides before the end of the 10 seconds ?

Comment: you mean just paused for a few seconds and let it move even when you are not scrolling after this few seconds? like you scrolling 10 times and 2 seconds one time then the slider will keep moving 20s discontinuous?